# Batch: If exist statement causes errorlevel to be 1 although it succeeded

Tags: batch-file, file-exists, errorlevel

In my batch file (a normal *.bat file), I want to check if a file exists. If it exists, it should be copied, if not, an output should be written to the shell. After the if statement, I want to check if the (possible) copy command executed successfully. I'm doing that with an errorlevel check.

But although the if-statement seems to work, the errorlevel after the statement is always 1. I know that the if-statement works because when the file does not exist, the respective message is written to the shell.

Here is the code:

```
if errorlevel 1 goto error
...     
if exist %my_path_and_file% (
copy %my_path_and_file% %my_target_path_and_file%

) ELSE (
echo File %immo_path_and_file% does not exist
)

if errorlevel 1 goto error    
...    
:error    
...
```

Why is the errorlevel always 1 after the if-statement, although the correct output is
File xxx does not exist
and the if-statement seemed to run successfully?

SOLVED: My mistake. The errorlevel was set to 1 by another statement BEFORE the IF statement. I also misplaced the first erroelevel check in my posted code above - sorry for that. There was some code between the first check and the IF statement which caused the errorlevel set to 0. I will correct it now. Thanks for all answers!

Comment: do you have spaces in file names?

Comment: And, in this code, how are you determining that the errorlevel is 1 after the if command? If errorlevel is 1, execution continues on the `:error` label, but if it is 0, execution continues on the next line, the `:error` label.

Comment: @npocmaka: No I don't. Example:SET my_path_and_file=".\Exports\folderone\test.txt"

Comment: @MCND: I have a lot of other statements after the second errorlevel check, which are not triggered. The output also shows me that it is exactly this check which "goes" to :error

Answer (score 2):

`if exist` doesn't set an `errorlevel`, even if the file doesn't exists:

```
C:\Users>if exist qwerty (echo true) else echo false
false

C:\Users>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\Users>if exist qwerty rem

C:\Users>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if %errorLevel% == 1 (
    goto error
) else (
    echo ok
)
```

Comment: Same result as with my check.